# How to upload a new version of a conda-forge package for a conda beginner

Tags: python, anaconda, conda-forge

I'm developing a python package that is primarily released using Anaconda, with the use of conda-forge for installing a few programs external to Python - namely ffmpeg, git and fluidsynth. My problem is that the current [fluidsynth release](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fluidsynth) on conda-forge does not include a Windows release.

However, I've found a GitHub repo that does contain the binaries for Fluidsynth. How can I add this release to conda-forge? I'm a complete beginner to using conda, and the guide on how to update feedstocks and recipes is totally over my head. I have created a [release](https://github.com/nicthib/fluidsynth/releases/tag/v1.1.11) of this build, but I'm totally lost on how to edit the `meta.yaml` file to add it to the feedstock.

So far, I have added the release link to the `source` field of the `meta.yaml` file, but where I get lost is the `build` and the `requirements` fields:

```yaml
{% set name = "fluidsynth-windows" %}
{% set version = "1.1.11" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}
source:
  url: https://github.com/nicthib/fluidsynth/archive/v{{ version }}.tar.gz
  sha256: ce11a3711c3c2bee5dafc9ffb573f9394ff6cbd581b251c33abbb414d91c6534
build:
  # Uncomment the following line if the package is pure Python and the recipe is exactly the same for all platforms.
  # It is okay if the dependencies are not built for all platforms/versions, although selectors are still not allowed.
  # See https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#noarch-python for more details.
  # noarch: python
  number: 0
  # If the installation is complex, or different between Unix and Windows, use separate bld.bat and build.sh files instead of this key.
  # By default, the package will be built for the Python versions supported by conda-forge and for all major OSs.
  # Add the line "skip: True  # [py<35]" (for example) to limit to Python 3.5 and newer, or "skip: True  # [not win]" to limit to Windows.
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv"

requirements:
  build:
    # If your project compiles code (such as a C extension) then add the required compilers as separate entries here.
    # Compilers are named 'c', 'cxx' and 'fortran'.
    - {{ compiler('c') }}
  host:
    - python
    - pip
  run:
    - python
```

I'm completely lost on how to approach this recipe, since the build is Windows binaries, and not a Python package. The build I have included runs right out of the box - no compiler needed. How do I approach writing a `meta.yaml` file for a release like this?

Comment: I think it would be preferable to fork [the current `fluidsynth-feedstock`](https://github.com/conda-forge/fluidsynth-feedstock) to include a Windows build, rather than creating a platform-specific package. Consider also reaching out to the maintainers of the feedstock to let them know your goal.

Comment: Good idea. I've opened an issue requesting this, but in the meantime I've figured out how to create a release on anaconda-cloud since the process is a bit more straightforward.